# How to enable auto start for an app in xiaomi programmatically

Tags: android

I would like to know whether the background service for any application can be provided by xiaomi?
I have service in my app which need to be running in background all the time , in all devices its working fine except Xiaomi, how it can be done programmatically?

Answer (score 11):

Works for xiaomi, oppo, vivo and oneplus phones as well.

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if("oneplus".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) { 
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListAct‌​ivity")); }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if  (list.size() > 0) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
```

Comment: What is for one plus?

Comment: @JanaBabu use this if ("oneplus".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListActivity"));
            }

Comment: How do we know if user has granted the Autostart or the not?

Comment: There is no way to know

Comment: @RaRa I'm getting error in opening settings on oneplus. any update on it ? has oneplus removed it.