# onTaskRemoved not being called in service above android 6.please can some one give better alternative

Tags: java, android

I've been using `onTaskRemoved()` method in a Service to detect when an app was removed from the device's RECENT list by swiping it away. I preform some logging and some other operations that need to take place when this happens. It works perfectly. For android below 6... But background service is being killed after swiping off in android 6.

```
     @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Log.e("ClearFromRecentSsss", "sttttts");
         Intent intent = new Intent("in.com.example");
            sendBroadcast(intent);           
        }
```

Comment: Is this a device dependent issue ? Did you check in several devices ?

Comment: ya i checked with several device  bt same issue is comming for all android above 6

Comment: Can you list out the devices you have tested.

Comment: Xiaomi redmi 3s,Lenovo Phab 2

Comment: even i tested in asus android 5 there its working fine

Comment: Local notification also i have implemented that is also not working....means background service getting killed in android 6 and above

Answer (score 1):

Some manufactures like xiaomi, Oppo have their own background strategy which is autostart.  You need to redirect user to auto start activity and tell user to switch on:
Go like this and allow your app to autostart:

```
Settings > permissions > Autostart
```

Autostart setting varies by manufactures like in Xiaomi you can find it in their SecurityCenter app.
Autostart is blocking your service to restart, So turn it on manually and the check again . I'm afraid there is no inbuilt API to do so . So you need to redirect users to specified screen as per manufactures to turn auto start On. Have a look at Links below:

1. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660216/ontaskremoved-not-getting-called-in-huawei-and-xiomi-devices)
2. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035284/how-to-enable-auto-start-for-an-app-in-xiaomi-programmatically)

Comment: can we auto start our app programmatically.

Comment: No . Read the answer as i said there is no inbuilt API for it Sp you can't you can just guide the users to do it manually .

Comment: facebook ,watsapp and other app there autostart was on in permission ..so how they are doing without asking user

Comment: Thats right you can research on that . I Did too but did not find any clue .