# Non-Sticky & Sticky services are destroyed when I close app from task manager

Tags: android, service

My application has a non-sticky service running, whenever I close the app from the task manager by swiping it, it also kills my service instantly. I am facing this issue only in Oppo phones.

Comment: You need to enable auto enable manager for oppo phones

Comment: @ShivamOberoi can you plz explain a lil..  how & why...

Comment: If you use START_NOT_STICKY then service will be removed when user kills the app.But if you use START_STICKY, even if user kills the app user service will get restarted.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev i know thats why i have mentioned both sticky and non sticky .. plus it working in other phones except my oppo f3 ..

Answer (score 1):

> On the Oppo F1 you need to add COL Reminder to the "Startup Manager"
>   to allow running in the background.
>
> Go to "Security Center". Click "Privacy Permissions" Then "Startup
>   manager" And allow "COL Reminder" to run in the background.
>
> ---
>
> If it is still not working please check this steps:
>
> Go to settings > Battery and Storage > Battery Manager > Tap on "Power
>   consumption details" > Optimize for excessive power consumption.  Now
>   uncheck all the apps you are facing issues with.
>   [image]

Comment: Right... please check on your phone and let us know its working or not

Comment: nope .. its not!! i have checked for startup boot and from battery management i have selected not to optimize for my app .. but all in vain so far

Answer (score 0):

Many smartphones like Xiamoi, Oppo, Vivo kills background services even if it is running with flag `START_STICKY` to improve resource/battery optimization.

**You can't set autostart to be enabled by-default programmatically.**

Many solutions/suggestions have already been answered in many threads.

This one is taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035284/how-to-enable-auto-start-for-an-app-in-xiaomi-programmatically), it takes user to respective auto-start/startup-manager/security-center, you can ask user to enable auto-start for your app by showing toast/alert, rest all depends on user:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
    } else if("oneplus".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) { 
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListAct‌​ivity")); }

    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if  (list.size() > 0) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

**P.S.** auto-start is enabled by-default for some apps like Facebook, Instagram and other Facebook family apps, they may have an agreement with device manufacturers.

Comment: i have already visited that thread and the answer above yours (from @Nirav Joshi) is almost the same but problem is that after enabling those options i still can't get the expected results

Comment: So, `Service` isn't running after enabling auto-start?

Comment: Sometimes it revokes after a time-period of 5-10 mins, depends on resources available and resources required by your service, please check in running services after 5-10 minutes.

Comment: ahan.. ok i will get back to this thread soon .. right now i m in a rush..