# Detect incoming and outgoing calls when app is closed

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have been working on an app that can detect incoming & outgoing calls in android and record them. I need to know which of my sim receives a call or make a call.

I can detect calls but unable to detect my number in case of dual sim. I have tried to check it from my call logs.

Here is my code:

```
private void fetchCallLogs(final Context context) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // get start of cursor
            Log.i("CallLogDetailsActivity", "Getting Log activity...");

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc");

            int accountId = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID);
            //Check if call was made from sim 1 or sim 2 , if it returns 0 its from sim 1 else if 1 its from sim 2.

            String callid = "0";
            if (cur.moveToFirst() == true) {
                String phNumber = cur.getString(accountId);
                int idSimId = getSimIdColumn(cur);

                if(idSimId >= 0){
                    callid = cur.getString(idSimId);
                }

                cur.close();


            }
        }
    }, 1500);
}

public static int getSimIdColumn(final Cursor c) {

    for (String s : new String[] { "sim_id", "simid","simId","simSlot", "sub_id","slot","simnum","slotId","slot_id","slotIdx" }) {
        int id = c.getColumnIndex(s);
        if (id >= 0) {
            Log.d("TAG", "sim_id column found: " + s);
            return id;
        }
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "no sim_id column found");
    return -1;
}
```

also tried to detect if using detecting sim slot

```
 String number = intent.getExtra("slot",-1);
```

but this doesn't work.

I need a code that can detect either sim number or slot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: service is what you need.

Comment: yes, I know it needs a service. can anyone help me out how to create such service?

Comment: it is easy. try it. if you got stuck, post another question with source code and error.

Comment: Recording isn't actually possible-  there's no API for that, on purpose.  The best you can do is record via mic and *hope* that the output is loud enough the mic picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons the your `BroadCastReceiver` not running when app closed..

> 1. Some mobiles not allow to run app in background like oppo,xiaomi,huawei etc.. to solve this issue try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035284/how-to-enable-auto-start-for-an-app-in-xiaomi-programmatically)
> 2. The latest Android version Oreo [Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

if these reasons not part of your problem then use the service. How to do that? [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824692/9868485)

Answer (score 0):

You should register your receiver implicitly in `AndroidManifest.xml`, for example like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".PhonecallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```