# Foreground Service for Location Android 8.0 above

Tags: android, service, foreground

This question has been asked many times but nothing seems to work..

I made a foreground service for location, it seems to work fine.. i get a notification and get the location as long as the activity is still open. As soon user swipes and kills the activity the foreground service remains in the notification and when I check-in running services it is still running, however, the location updates stop coming.

When I further investigated I found that although the foreground service is not killed its main processes which were google GM location was killed. Hence no location is coming.

The phone I am testing on is Xiami Mi Mix3, with Android 8.0. Does anyone have any ideas..

thanks

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303799/9868485

Comment: Look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550113/5978440)

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Comment: Thanks allot for all comments.. I  have already made sure app is in autostart of Xiomi, changed the battery performance setting to no restrictions.. what i am confused is why is the Service still running but the process is killed..